# in freebsd add DHCP IP as an alias on top of statically configured IP to the same interface on console (not by config files)?

Tags: freebsd, console, dhcp, ifconfig, dhclient

I need to find a way to configure an alias by DHCP but not touch statically configured IP of the same interface and have to do it all by console, not by editing some conf files.

As far as know you can not use dhclient for aliases. I can work with additional virtual interfaces as long as they physically work from same interface? Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer in [here](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-net/2010-December/027234.html)
posting so anyone else has a problem of this sort can maybe find answer easier. Thanks to original poster (Rozhuk Ivan).